# PolyData with nonconvex polygons

Tags: python, convex, pyvista

Just to replicate the error, let's consider the succession of points describing a nonconvex polygon:

```
[0. , 0. , 0. ],
[1. , 0. , 0. ],
[1. , 0.5, 0. ],
[0.5, 0.5, 0. ],
[0.5, 1. , 0. ],
[1. , 1. , 0. ],
[1. , 1.5, 0. ],
[0. , 1.5, 0. ]
```

This data should represent a nonconvex polygon looking like [image: c shape polygon]

But when trying to set this up using PyVista's `PolyData` constructor, as:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista

b = 0.5
c = 0.5
points = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, b, 0],
    [1-b, b, 0],
    [1-b, b+c, 0],
    [1, b+c, 0],
    [1, 2*b+c, 0],
    [0, 2*b+c, 0],
])

face = np.concatenate([
    [9],
    np.arange(9),
    [0],
])
polygon = pyvista.PolyData(
    points,
    face)

polygon.plot()
```

I somehow get a distorted version of it:

[image: c shaped polygon with a triangular artifact in the hole of the "c"]

Is there something I'm missing from pyvista documentation?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in your code but that's not the reason you're seeing this artifact.

The bug in your code is that you have 8 points but use `np.arange(9)` which has the wrong length and the wrong maximum value (it contains point index 8 at the end which doesn't exist). You can suspect that something's not right from

```py
>>> polygon.n_cells
2
```

The faces you passed have a trailing zero, which would mean a cell of size 0. The larger issue is the reference to a non-existent point 8 in the first face; I suspect this might even lead to segfaults later.

You can fix this bug by using `np.arange(8)`, or with some future-proofing, with

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista

b = 0.5
c = 0.5
points = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, b, 0],
    [1-b, b, 0],
    [1-b, b+c, 0],
    [1, b+c, 0],
    [1, 2*b+c, 0],
    [0, 2*b+c, 0],
])

face = np.concatenate([
    [points.shape[0] + 1],
    np.arange(points.shape[0]),
    [0],
])
polygon = pyvista.PolyData(points, face)

polygon.plot()
```

Now, the problem is that the artifact is still there. I've run into this occasionally, and I don't know if it's a PyVista bug or a VTK one (probably the latter). You can switch between a wireframe and a surface model in the plot window by pressing `w` and `s`, respectively; it's evident that something's not right because the wireframe looks correct.

But anyway you can get around the issue by breaking down your concave polygon face into triangles using the `triangulate()` filter:

```py
polygon = pyvista.PolyData(points, face).triangulate()
polygon.plot()
```

Now this polygon looks correct in a surface render. But of course instead of a single cell it now contains multiple (6) triangles. For most applications this is perfectly fine, in fact there are even filters which *only* work with triangulated inputs. So this might be a perfectly fine solution to your problem.

Comment: While VTK allows you to create a concave cell, many filters and plotting assume that the cell is complex.  VTK even has a class to help detecting nonconcavity of cells: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellValidator.html#details

Comment: @MatthewFlamm so it sounds very much like a VTK issue, then.